# I can't properly generate a kotlin object capable of redeeming the JSON date

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

So how should I write my Evolution class so that it works at the time of the server response and collect so much data that comes in JSON?

My problem is in this field "checklists" I can not mount it on the object because it complains when I make it an array or an object

JSON:

```
{
  "message": "Consulta realizada com sucesso",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 120,
      "tipo_evolucao_id": 5,
      "tipo_evolucao": "Frequência Cardíaca",
      "data_hora": "20\/10\/2021 às 13:39",
      "responsavel": "Vinicius Marconi Vasconcelos Berni",
      "evolucao": "Paciente vem apresentando resistência na administração dos medicamentos.",
      "checklists": {
        "Frequência Cardíaca": {
          "label": "Frequência Cardíaca",
          "itens": [
            {
              "pergunta": "Frequência observada",
              "resposta": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "tipo_evolucao_id": 1,
      "tipo_evolucao": "Necessidades Fisiológicas",
      "data_hora": "19\/10\/2021 às 11:52",
      "responsavel": "Vinicius Marconi Vasconcelos Berni",
      "evolucao": "foi foi e foi",
      "checklists": {
        "Evacuação": {
          "label": "Evacuação",
          "itens": [
            {
              "pergunta": "Tipo",
              "resposta": "\"liquida\""
            },
            {
              "pergunta": "Quantidade",
              "resposta": "\"normal\""
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

My Class Kotlin:

```
class Evolution {
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    var message: String? = null

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    var data: List<EvoData>? = null
}
class EvoData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("tipo_evolucao_id")
    @Expose
    var tipoEvolucaoId: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("tipo_evolucao")
    @Expose
    var tipoEvolucao: String? = null

    @SerializedName("data_hora")
    @Expose
    var dataHora: String? = null

    @SerializedName("responsavel")
    @Expose
    var responsavel: String? = null

    @SerializedName("evolucao")
    @Expose
    var evolucao: String? = null

    @SerializedName("checklists")
    @Expose
    var checklists: CheckLists? = null
}
class CheckLists {

    @Expose
    var checklist:  Checklist? = null

}
class Checklist {
    @SerializedName("label")
    @Expose
    var label: String? = null


    @SerializedName("itens")
    @Expose
    var itens: List<Itens>? = null

}
class Itens {

    @SerializedName("pergunta")
    @Expose
    var pergunta: String? = null

    @SerializedName("resposta")
    @Expose
    var resposta: String? = null
}
```

Log Error:

```
D/erro: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 1132 path $.data[2].checklists
```

So how should I write my Evolution class so that it works at the time of the server response and collect so much data that comes in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The `checklists` JSON attribute is a Map, so try the following:

```java
class EvoData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("tipo_evolucao_id")
    @Expose
    var tipoEvolucaoId: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("tipo_evolucao")
    @Expose
    var tipoEvolucao: String? = null

    @SerializedName("data_hora")
    @Expose
    var dataHora: String? = null

    @SerializedName("responsavel")
    @Expose
    var responsavel: String? = null

    @SerializedName("evolucao")
    @Expose
    var evolucao: String? = null

    @SerializedName("checklists")
    @Expose
    var checklists: Map<String, Checklist> = emptyMap()
}
```

You can delete your `CheckLists` class.

Comment: @João Gabriel did this help?